# Key error on text formatting even after double brackets used on Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, formatting

I want to format a text which is html content which will be embedded to an email. I'm preparing the mail with Python 3.

I know that in Python text formatting can be performed by using "f" before the text to be formatted and then key values are written with single brackets like {key}. 
Text I'm formatting is;

```
html = f"""
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
   body {{width: 100% !important;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;}}

/* force default font sizes */

.ExternalClass {{width: 100%;}}

.ExternalClass,
.ExternalClass p,
.ExternalClass span,
.ExternalClass font,
.ExternalClass td,
.ExternalClass div {{
    line-height: 100%;
  }}

    /* Hotmail */

    table td {{border-collapse: collapse;}}

    @media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {{
        .maxW {{
            width: 600px !important;
          }}
      }}
  </style>
    </head>

<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; -ms-                            
text-size-adjust:none;" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0"
  marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
  <table bgcolor="#CCCCCC" width="100%" border="0" align="center"     
 cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
  <td valign="top">
    <table width="100%" class="maxW" style="max-width: 100%; margin: auto;" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td valign="top" align="center">
          <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <tr>
              <td align="center" valign="middle" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 24px; color: #353535; padding:3%; padding-top:40px; padding-bottom:40px;">
                {months[now.month-1]} Ayı Jira Raporu
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="left" valign="middle" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 24px; color: #353; padding:3%; padding-top:40px; padding-bottom:40px;">
                Genel Durum
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
                      <tr>
                        <td width="100%" align="center">
                          <br>
                          <img src="cid:image1">
                          <br>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="70%" align="left" bgcolor="#252525" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #EEEEEE; padding:10px; padding-right:0;">
                          Grup
                        </td>
                        <td width="30%" align="right" bgcolor="#252525" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #EEEEEE; padding:10px; padding-left:0;">
                          Talep Sayısı
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="70%" align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #252525; padding:10px; padding-right:0;">
                          YY Ankara
                        </td>
                        <td width="30%" align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #252525; padding:10px; padding-left:0;">
                          {len(yy_ankara_issues)}
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="70%" align="left" bgcolor="#EEEEEE" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #252525; padding:10px; padding-right:0;">
                          IG Ankara
                        </td>
                        <td width="30%" align="right" bgcolor="#EEEEEE" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #252525; padding:10px; padding-left:0;">
                          {len(ig_ankara_issues)}
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="70%" align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #252525; padding:10px; padding-right:0;">
                          YY İstanbul
                        </td>
                        <td width="30%" align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #252525; padding:10px; padding-left:0;">
                          {len(yy_istanbul_issues)}
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="70%" align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #252525; padding:10px; padding-left:10px;">
                          <b>Toplam Açılan Talep Sayısı</b>
                        </td>
                        <td width="30%" align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #252525; padding:10px; padding-left:0;">
                          <b>{len(all_issues)}</b>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="70%" align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #252525; padding:10px; padding-left:10px;">
                          Bu ay açılan talepler ortalama
                          <b> {len(all_closed_issues)} </b> günde kapanmıştır.
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </td>
              <tr>
                <td align="center">
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
                        <tr>
                          <td width="70%" align="left" bgcolor="#252525" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #EEEEEE; padding:10px; padding-right:0;">
                            Talep Önceliğine Göre Talep Sayıları
                          </td>
                          <td width="30%" align="right" bgcolor="#252525" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #EEEEEE; padding:10px; padding-left:0;">
                            Talep Sayısı
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <tr>
            <td align="left" align="middle" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #353535; padding:3%; padding-top:40px; padding-bottom:40px;">
              İyi Çalışmalar
            </td>
          </tr>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
 """
```

Then I'm using tabulate to iteratively create tables;

```
html = html.format(table=tabulate(data, tablefmt="html"))
```

At this point Python gives the keyError. 
HTML styling uses lots of brackets, but I've doubled all brackets in styling. So why I'm still having this keyError ?

Comment: Which keyError are you getting? I couldn't try it coz there are many variables that you have defined earlier. Can you check if you have defined all the variables and doubled all braces in styling?

Comment: KeyError: 'width'. I guess somehow double brackets are not working. Because it is trying to find words in double brackets.